# Порядок сортировки FindFirstFile и FindNextFile

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток!

В папке 10 файлов.

Функции FindFirstFile и FindNextFile находят файлы в таком порядке:

```
Файл-1.nnm
Файл-10.nnm
Файл-2.nnm
...
```

А нужно так:

```
Файл-1.nnm
Файл-2.nnm
...
Файл-10.nnm
```

Почему они находят файлы в таком порядке, и как можно исправить?

Comment: `This is because FindFirstFile does no sorting of the search results.` Так что сортируйте самостоятельно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Формально файлы могут возвращаться в произвольно порядке, хотя фактически на ntfs/fat почти наверняка будет лексикографический.

В любом случае, сортировать, тем более, с учётом числовых значений, надо список после его формирования.

Comment: А в Ex варианте этих функций то же самое?

Comment: Как бы Вы отсортировали? В один массив без разделителей все имена, или в двумерный массив где каждый отдельно, или вообще в вектор? А может в <algorithm> уже готовая заготовка сортировки есть? Как лучше?

Comment: Вопрос не в "как лучше", а "как нужно" :) В <algorithm> есть замечательная заготовка, называется `sort`, просто к ней нужно написать правильный компаратор...

Comment: @Harry, но компаратор придётся писать - вроде плюсы такое сравнение строк сами не умеют, в отличие от js. Или умеют?

Comment: @Qwertiy Естественно. В этом и вопрос - "как нужно", определяется компаратором...

Comment: @Harry, компаратор компаратору рознь. В js тоже компаратор, но я могу вот так: `["ёж 1", "ёж 2", "ёж 10"].sort(new Intl.Collator("ru-RU", { usage: "sort", numeric: true }).compare)` и получится ['ёж 1', 'ёж 2', 'ёж 10'] - в плюсах есть такое?

Comment: @Qwertiy Нетрудно и написать. js-запись понять куда труднее...

Comment: Я совершенно не пойму что я должен вернуть в 3 параметре sort - bool Compare?
Хоть примерно логику поясните!

Comment: Ему как то надо сказать что "Файл-10, Файл-11 и т.д." > "Файл-2", но как?

Comment: @KoTTBarsik, в си++ компаратор должен возвращать, меньше ли первый аргумент второго. Причём очень важно при равенстве вернуть false, а не мусор.

Comment: А что такое первый и второй аргументы? Я "." и "0" должен сравнить? Что то ничего не понимаю.

Comment: @KoTTBarsik, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort